# Disabling MSTest temp directory in TeamCity

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, continuous-integration, teamcity, mstest

I'm using TeamCity Professional for building and testing my code continually.

I have some MSTest based tests that work fine in VS2010 on my PC but fail on the build server.

I snooped around and discovered that upon testing, TeamCity creates a temporary directory in it's `TEMP_DIR` (configurable) and copies only the "first relation" dependencies to the test DLL.

For instance: my test uses `NHibernate.dll` which is copied to the temp directory but its dependencies (i.e `NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle`) don't get copied, and the test fails with an `IO.FileNotFound` exception.

Is there any way I can just run the tests from the test projects output directory (Test/bin/debug)?

If not, how can I specify which DLLs should be copied to the temp directory?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can add a **TestSettings** file in your solution that will describe all the files to deploy.

First, add a **TestSettings** file. Open it, and in the "**Deployment**" tab, add all the file you need (your .dll).
Then on TeamCity, in the MSTest build step, specifiy the TestSettings file to use in the "**Additional command parameters**" area. Exemple: *"/testsettings:Local.Testsettings"*

This way, all the files you specify in the deployment items will be copied in the temp directory.

Comment: This helped me out - thanks!  Two notes that might help others: First, I was able to specify the xxx.Testsettings file in the "MSTest run configuration file:" for the TeamCity settings.  Second, this field expects the path to the file from the working directory in TeamCity, which is essentially the top level of your repository.